# Xcode Instruments, Network Connections: total bytes sent was less than actual

Tags: ios, xcode, networking, instruments

I am using the tool of Network Connections in Xcode Instruments, but found that the total bytes out there is less than i actually send.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUz6V.png)

1. from the picture of instuments (foreground), the total bytes is only 930KiB.
2. from the picture of Debug session in Xcode (background), the total bytes is 4 MB
3. I have tried to capture data from wireshark and anaylse the data, 4MB is correct.

My Xcode is Version 10.1(10B61), and debug iphone is iphone7 with ios12.1 and use wifi for test.

My question is that why bytes in Instruments, Network Connections get less that actual ?

Comment: ok, it seems its a bug on instruments. when i collect instruments data on my iphone through developer menu and then open it on pc instrument tool,  i can get perfect data. But when i collect data from pc, it will always leave out some data.

Comment: Update your question with the steps you are taking where the data is left out. Explain what you mean by collect data from pc. Keep in mind that running Apple's developer tools on a Hackintosh or on a virtual machine on a Windows PC is unsupported by Apple. I doubt Instruments supports receiving network data from a Windows PC.